# How do I get cityname, province, state, from PHAsset in iOS 8 Photos Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Is it possible to access the location information such as city name and state from a PHAsset.  The iOS Photos app shows very specific location information such as Belltown, Seattle, Washington, USA.  However, all that I've been able to access from a PHAsset is the CALocation from the location property.  Which I believe only provides me with geo-coords and therefore would still require reverse-geocoding.  I have thousands of photos to reverse geocode per user.   So, I would like to avoid having to do reverse geocoding and simply access the human readable location information that Apple is already displaying in the Photos app.

In short, given a PHAsset object, how do I access the cityname for the photo location, without using a reverse geocoding service?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In `PHAsset` there is a property for location, use it.

```
static NSString *const kCityString  = @"City";
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *cityString;
```

...

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

    CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks.lastObject;

    // deprecated since iOS 11.0
    strongSelf.cityString = placemark.addressDictionary[kCityString];

    // or equivalent
    strongSelf.cityString = placemark.locality;
}];
```

go and look at `CLPlacemark`for other properties.

Comment: In short, given a PHAsset object, how do I access the cityname for the photo location, without using a reverse geocoding service?  You are using a rate limited reverse geocoding service.  The point of the question is to avoid this...

Comment: In PHAsset there is a property, `location`. Then how you are going to access those data (city, province and so on) depends on you. There is native way out like the upper one or you can use Google Maps API. If there would have been any other easiest way to find out all that information Apple just didn't make `CLGeocoder` and Google there's Maps API.

Comment: There are strict limits one what you can do with the maps API, so it doesn't solve the issue of reverse geocoding a large number of photos.  Notice that in the photos app, everything has already been reverse geo-coded. So, it would be ideal to simply access that data...

Comment: May be this will be helpful... There is Exif dictionary of photo...may be there will be something interesting?.. I cannot test by myself, have my device broken... `CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:info[@"PHImageFileURLKey"]];
    NSLog(@"properties: %@", ciImage.properties);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps API to perform geocoding translations on a latitude and longitude. See more here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding.

Then you could cache the results and reuse them if you query locations that are very close. Another thing would be to use the GeoLite geo location database, but this is some 100 megs..

[See here for download](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)

Comment: This involves using a reverse geo coder api that is limited to reverse geocoding a small number of photo locations.